# How to use cookies in Android Webview

Tags: android-webview

I am using a webview to render the contents of my Website.

I want to use Cookies in this webview to Auto Sign-In the users in that web site.

So, can anybody help how to use cookies in Android webview?

Comment: have you tried the normal method like you do in web browsers to enable cookies? Did it not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable your browser to accept cookies using `CookieSyncManager`. Everything else you wrote regarding cookies on your html side will work fine.

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
setContentView(webview);      
webview.loadUrl([MY URL]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Darpan.  Is using CookieSyncManager and CookieManager secure?  If not then how we can securely use Cookie with WebView?

Comment: CookieSyncManager is as secure as it is on web. So go ahead. If answer helps you, you can mark it accepted or useful.

Comment: How to do the same for Android Marshmallow?